# How to add type annotations to generic impl block where the struct itself doesn't require a generic parameter?

Tags: generics, rust

I have gotten stuck in trying to help the compiler to infer the type of a generic impl block. Here is the code:

```
pub struct Foo {
    /*some non generic fields*/
}

impl<T: AsBytes> Foo {
    pub fn new(/*some non generic params*/) -> Self {
        ...
        let size = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
        ...
    }

    pub fn update(&self, data: &T) {
        ...
        let data = data.as_bytes();
        ...
        let size = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
        ...
    }
}
```

When using Foo the compiler can usually infer the type of `T` but in one place when calling `let var = Foo::new()` I get this error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/bar/foo.rs:98:13
   |
98 |             Foo::new(param1, param2);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

How to I annotate the generic type? What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

---

You basically have this:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl<T> Foo {
}
```

which causes

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:3:6
  |
3 | impl<T> Foo {
  |      ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

because generics don't make sense for an implementation item by itself. They only make sense for a type or method.

Basically, you want

```rust
pub struct Foo {
    size: usize,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new<T>() -> Self {
        let size = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
        Self {
            size
        }
    }

    pub fn update<T>(self, data: &T) -> Self {
        self
    }
}
```

which can be called as `Foo::new::<String>()` for example. However a user could update a `Foo` created for a `String` with another type:

```rust
let foo = Foo::new::<String>();
foo.update::<u32>();
```

It is not clear that this is what you want.

If you don't, then you need to make `Foo` generic over `T`:

```rust
use core::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct Foo<T> {
    size: usize,
    _dummy: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let size = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
        Self {
            size,
            _dummy: PhantomData
        }
    }

    pub fn update(self, data: &T) -> Self {
        self
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to force the `update` and `new` to use the same concrete type in the end which wouldn't be the case if `update` and `new` took their own generic type parameter so I guess the PhantomData option makes the most sense. I haven't seen the error you gave only the one I posted.

Comment: You'd only get this error after you solved all the other errors unfortunately.